# sudo systemctl mongod restart terminates mongod and it will not start again

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, ubuntu

I installed mongodb on my ubuntu 16.04 machine on aws using [these instructions](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/) with a slight deviation: I ran the mongod process with  `sudo systemctl mongod start`  as from what I have read, that works better with Ubuntu 16.04.  I fiddled around a little, created a user, added

`security: 
    authentication: 'enabled'`

edit:

`security: 
    authorization: 'enabled'`

/edit

(with 2 spaces, 4 spaces, and a tab iteratively)
to /etc/mongod.conf and went to restart with

`sudo systemctl mongod restart`

but now checking with `netstat -tupln`, mongod is not running.  I also tried restarting with `sudo systemctl mongod start` but that's not working either.  Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The config key is not correct. It's authorization, not authentication

```
security: 
    authorization: enabled
```

See https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/reference/configuration-options/#security-options

Answer (score 0):

you said `sudo systemctl mongod start` and then `sudo systemctl restart mongod` - look at the position of start and restart, you're using systemctl incorrectly.

you can use also use `systemctl status mongod`

also check upstart or syslog in `/var/log/`, you should find an error there explaining why the service didn't start.

Comment: sudo systemctl status mongod
● mongod.service - High-performance, schema-free document-oriented database
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2017-11-28 00:26:16 UTC; 3min 8s ago
     Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
  Process: 2857 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf (code=exited, status=2)
 Main PID: 2857 (code=exited, status=2)

Comment: Nov 28 00:26:16 ip-172-31-80-196 systemd[1]: Started High-performance, schema-free document-oriented database.
Nov 28 00:26:16 ip-172-31-80-196 mongod[2857]: Error parsing YAML config file: yaml-cpp: error at line 30, column 15:
Nov 28 00:26:16 ip-172-31-80-196 mongod[2857]: try '/usr/bin/mongod --help' for more information
Nov 28 00:26:16 ip-172-31-80-196 systemd[1]: mongod.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=2/INVALIDARGUME
Nov 28 00:26:16 ip-172-31-80-196 systemd[1]: mongod.service: Unit entered failed state.

Comment: Nov 28 00:26:16 ip-172-31-80-196 systemd[1]: mongod.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.

Comment: apologies for formatting on my traceback posting.  I've tried it both ways, I get an error message when it's the wrong way

Comment: I'm gonna wipe this post in a little while after people have read my responses and start fresh in the morning, I've been at this all day and I'm being too careless to get useful help from stackoverflow

Comment: its telling you the issue: Error parsing YAML config file: yaml-cpp: error at line 30, column 15

Comment: Fixed that error.  I'm getting: "Unrecognized option: security"

Comment: here's a copy pasted snippet of my config file:


security:

  authorization='enabled'

with a newline and 2 spaces between security and authorization

Comment: try changing the authorization line to look like this:  authorization: enabled

Comment: I find people do more wonders, particularly when it comes to general topics rather than specific problems :P but if you don't have anything in particular, don't go doing exactly what I can do

Comment: got it running.  Onto the next problem *masochistic sigh*

Comment: I prefer watching youtube tutorials to understand things than to read endless pages of documentation... you can find a crash course on yaml on youtube there are plenty around.  good job on solving the issue :)